# How Do I add rows to Pandas dataframe to only the first 100 indices, while the other part is left unchanged?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row, multiple-columns, indices

I want to add more rows to only the first 105 indices of a dataframe (with zero elements in the columns), while the rest part of the row is left unchanged with a frequency of 2mins.

An example of dataframe df is seen below.

`Time   Z(dB) 0   1900-01-01 10:02:00   0.000 1   1900-01-01 10:04:00   0.000 2   1900-01-01 10:06:00   0.000 3   1900-01-01 10:08:00   0.000 4   1900-01-01 10:10:00   0.000 5   1900-01-01 10:12:00   0.000 6   1900-01-01 10:14:00   0.000 7   1900-01-01 10:16:00   0.000 8   1900-01-01 10:18:00   0.000 9   1900-01-01 10:20:00   0.000 10  1900-01-01 10:22:00   0.000 11  1900-01-01 10:24:00   0.000 12  1900-01-01 10:26:00   0.000 13  1900-01-01 10:28:00   0.000 14  1900-01-01 10:30:00   0.000 15  1900-01-01 10:32:00   0.000 16  1900-01-01 10:34:00   0.000 17  1900-01-01 10:36:00   0.000 18  1900-01-01 10:38:00   0.000 19  1900-01-01 10:40:00   0.000 20  1900-01-01 10:42:00   0.000 21  1900-01-01 10:44:00   0.000 22  1900-01-01 10:46:00   0.000 23  1900-01-01 10:48:00   0.000 24  1900-01-01 10:50:00   0.000 25  1900-01-01 10:52:00   0.000 26  1900-01-01 10:54:00   0.000 27  1900-01-01 10:56:00   0.000 28  1900-01-01 10:58:00   0.000 29  1900-01-01 11:00:00   0.000 33  1900-01-01 11:02:00   0.000 34  1900-01-01 11:04:00   0.000 35  1900-01-01 11:06:00   0.000 36  1900-01-01 11:08:00   0.000 37  1900-01-01 11:10:00   0.000 38  1900-01-01 11:12:00   0.000 39  1900-01-01 11:14:00   0.000`

I have used script below but it only add new rows but doesn't go beyond the 105th indices. Beyond 105th row, I want the remain dataframe to remain unchanged.

```
df = df.set_index("Time")

idx = pd.date_range("1900-01-01 10:02:00", "1900-01-01 12:32:00", freq="1min")
df = df.reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
```